# Sublime Text 2 config - Let space save the file

Tags: vim, key-bindings, sublimetext

Sublime Text 2 already supports normal Vim bindings. However, I'd like to have it support saving the current file when pressing space in command mode.

This key binding has become one of my number one features I love about vim.

However, when trying to write this key binding, Sublime Text 2 seems to ignore it:

```
{ "keys": ["space"], "command": "save",
  "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sublime Text 2 seems to not recognize "space".
It much rather has to be like this:

```
{ "keys": [" "], "command": "save",
  "context":
  [
    { "key": "setting.command_mode" }
  ]
}
```